# Revealing Module - whose target lacks a construct signature?

Tags: typescript

Why this code in typescript 3.9.2 gets me this error:

> 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly
> has an 'any' type.

Code is:

```
const Module = function(){

  function sayHello(){
    console.log('Hello');
  }

  return {
    sayHello: sayHello
  }
};

let module: any = new Module();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend you to use ES6 classes. but in case you want to keep using functions, then the below solution will work for you:

```
 interface Module {
  sayHello: () => void;
}

const Module = function(){

  function sayHello(){
    console.log('Hello');
  }

  return {
    sayHello: sayHello
  }
} as any as { new (): Module; };
  
let module = new Module();
```

If you want to use classes then you can simply write:

```
class Module {

  sayHello() {
    return console.log('Hello');
  }

};

let module = new Module();

module.sayHello();
```

[Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBAlgdgLgpgJwGYEMDGcwFkD2ATAVwBtMBvAWACgwwBnFATwAk4iicAuMACgEowAvAD4wANxwQ8AbioBfKlTQ4otGNnzFMAsEgJQ0MCMr4VKVGrv2HldRizY4T5mmCUqcJAHTsA5twDk9uz%20vDLUYPJm4QhwMAQIUGCmLrbMrOxc9GkOzpGyYCi0BVAMBUWkYFBwAO48vFy4hCRSES0gwAqUaESFRY2aSZ00WUGO-MkuMXEJrsq0HnDeOH6B6TghYTSRcmFUJGoAthokgpU16k1wfLuUR5eeI2vXQA)

Answer (score 0):

`new` is for instantiating classes. But the revealing module pattern is just a function that returns an object.

You want to create your module by calling it like any normal function, and not like it's a class constructor.

```
let module = Module();
module.sayHello() // logs 'Hello'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsiAJgVwDYFMYF4YDNljBQCW4AFAJQDeAUDHgUaWDBAIYCeAEuqqiJVr16oSCAwA6fgHMyAch58QcigG46MAL40NAJ3RRkulkOHtuvfgC5WnRfw3bN6mhlgBbJGkw4EKDJTqnv7oEub2AhQwAPTRMDIQMAqWykA)